# How to "echo" colored messages without "-e" option nor intermediate variable?

Tags: bash, shell, terminal, echo, ansi

I really struggle understanding the behavior of `echo` (and others such commands) while processing [ANSI escape codes](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ANSI_escape_code) to print colored messages.

I know I can use the `-e` option like this:

```
echo -e "\e[32m FOO \e[0m"
```

My message will be successfully colored.

Also, I noticed that I could assign the output of `echo -e` to a variable, and then re-use this variable in a new `echo` command **without the `-e` option**, and this would work anyway.

```
foo=$(echo -e "\e[32m FOO \e[0m")
echo $foo
```

So, what are the actual "raw bytes" emitted by `echo -e` when encountering ANSI codes? What does my `foo` variable contain? How could I integrate them directly in my `echo "??? FOO ???"` without needing the `-e` option?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The "raw output" of your initial `echo` will contain actual Escape characters (ASCII code 27, octal 033) instead of `\e`.  The rest of the string remains as is.  It's the `-e` option to `echo` in `bash` that replaces the `\e` character sequences with the Escape characters (just like it would replace `\t` by a tab etc.)

To incorporate an Escape character directly into `$foo` without going through `echo -e`, you would have to type an actual literal Escape character into the string.

In `bash`, you can type a literal Escape character by pressing <kbd>Ctrl+V</kbd> followed by <kbd>Esc</kbd>.

In a terminal, this would look like

```
foo="^[[32mFOO^[[0m"
```

where each `^[` is generated by <kbd>Ctrl+V</kbd> followed by <kbd>Esc</kbd>.

Or, you could use `$'...'` ("C string interpolation" in `bash`) to expand `\e`:

```
foo=$'\e[32mFOO\e[0m'
```

Comment: Perfect, thanks a lot, it's crystal clear now! ANSI sequences are introduced by the special `Esc` value, which is not printable, hence the `-e` option which eases its usage using ascii `\e`.

Comment: [Do not forget `foo=$'\e[32mFOO\e[0m'`.](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/65819/5132)